# What's the difference between colon ":" and fat arrow "=>"

Tags: ruby, syntax, hash, hashrocket

What's the difference between colon `:` and fat arrow `=>` in Ruby? Or when to use what?

```
:foo => true
foo: true
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The syntax is for defining Hash key/value pairs, and the difference depends on the Ruby version.

Supported in both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9

```
:foo => true
```

Supported only in Ruby 1.9

```
foo: true
```

If you're developing in Ruby 1.9 you should probably use the syntax:

```
foo: true
```

as it appears to be the direction the community is moving in.

Comment: Where did you hear that `=>` would be deprecated?

Comment: Yeah, where did you hear `=>` is going to be deprecated? I don't recall such a thing. And even if it were true, it would break the main Hash functionality that any object can serve as the key. So, only symbols could be used as keys if that happened! eg: `{Object => Object}` would no longer exist [that was pseudo code of a sort].

Comment: Sorry I can't recall where I heard that I may have made it up.  I've removed the reference to it eventually being deprecated.

Comment: You may have heard that `=>` is obsolete from http://peepcode.com/blog/2011/rip-ruby-hash-rocket-syntax

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: That blog post is overly dramatic nonsense. Blarg. Don't worry, I know you know that already :)

Answer (score 10):

The latter is the new Hash syntax introduced in 1.9. See, for example:

http://breakthebit.org/post/8453341914/ruby-1-9-and-the-new-hash-syntax

The hashes that the two lines generate are identical.

Comment: This is only for when the key is a symbol. If you want another object for the key, you'll need the fat arrow as before.

Comment: On that point, note that `{"key": "value"}` will be silently converted to `{:key=>"value"}` - the string will be turned into a symbol.  If you want a string key, use `{"key"=>"value"}`.