# What is the "id:" syntax in a hash?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between colon “:” and fat arrow “=>”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198811/whats-the-difference-between-colon-and-fat-arrow)

I recently came across this line:

```
<%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
```

I know about Hashes and the immutable keys that look like `{:id => "logo"}` but what is `id:`? If this is a hash, why does it not follow the normal convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the new syntax introduced with Ruby 1.9. You can write it like that, or you could write it like this also:

```
{ :id => "logo" }
```

The JSON style is just supported as a shorter alternative, and for people who like JavaScript.

Comment: I always thought it was for people who hate anyone using Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Actually, it is a transitional feature for introducing "proper" keyword arguments in a mostly backwards-compatible fashion in a future version of Ruby.