# How to efficiently sort on 2 string attributes, either of which may be nil, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance, sorting

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :size, :color

  def <=>
    ...


foo1 = Foo.new( size: 'large', color: 'blue'  )
foo2 = Foo.new( size: 'small'                 )
foo3 = Foo.new( color: 'green'                )
foo4 = Foo.new( size: 'small', color: 'red'   )
  ...
```

Size is ordered small, nil, medium, large, super-sized. Color is ordered green, nil, blue, red.

How to efficiently sort first by size, then by color?

Comment: "then by age?" -- you have never mentioned any *age*, did you mean *color*?

Comment: Also, what kind of notation is `size: 'large', color: 'blue'` never seen it.

Comment: Same as `:size => 'large', :color => 'blue'`. Ruby 1.9 hash syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198811/whats-the-difference-between-colon-and-fat-arrow

Comment: should nil be considered as very large or very small?

Comment: @Shawn - nil is actually in the middle. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :size, :color
  VALID_COLORS = ["small",nil,"medium","large","super-sized"]
  VALID_SIZES  = ["green", nil, "blue", "red" ]

  def size_pos
    VALID_COLORS.index(size) || -1
  end

  def color_pos
    VALID_SIZES.index(color) || -1
  end

  def initialize(opts={})
    @size=opts[:size]
    @color=opts[:color]
  end

  def <=>(other)
    [size_pos,color_pos] <=> [other.size_pos, other.color_pos]
  end
end

foo1 = Foo.new( size: 'large', color: 'blue'  )
foo2 = Foo.new( size: 'small'                 )
foo3 = Foo.new( color: 'green'                )
foo4 = Foo.new( size: 'small', color: 'red'   )

[foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4].sort

#[#<Foo:0x000000020848d0 @size="small", @color=nil>, 
 #<Foo:0x00000002065700 @size="small", @color="red">, 
 #<Foo:0x00000002074868 @size=nil, @color="green">, 
 #<Foo:0x0000000208da98 @size="large", @color="blue"> ]
```

You could improve performance by extracting out the positions into a class variable hash or constant instead of calling the index each time.

Answer (score 2):

First I'd explicitly declare the order:

```
@@size_order = {
    'small' => 1, 
    'medium' => 2, 
    'large' => 3, 
    'super-sized' => 4
}

@@color_order = {
    'green' => 1,
    'blue' => 2,
    'red' => 3
}
```

then you can just definite the `<=>` method along the lines of:

```
def <=> ( o )
    if (@size == o.size)
        if (@color == o.color) 
            return 0
        else
            return (@@color_order[@color] > @@color_order[o.color]) ? 1 : -1
        end
    else
        return (@@size_order[@size] > @@size_order[o.size]) ? 1 : -1
    end
end
```

Here's [a test example](http://ideone.com/PL37JP).

But it would be probably *better* (more OOP) to subclass `Foo` with two classes: `Color` and `Size` and define a `<=>` for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'foos' is a collection of foo objects:

```
foos.sort_by {|f| [ f.size || '', f.color || '' ]}
```

This might be more efficient than using sort or defining <=>.  You could use something other than the empty string when the attribute is nil if you want to adjust the sort order.  For increased flexibility, you could do something like this:

```
def sort_by_size
  foos.sort_by {|f| [ f.size || '', f.color || '' ]}
end

def sort_by_color
  foos.sort_by {|f| [ f.color|| '', f.size|| '' ]}
end
```