# Ruby Data Types

Tags: ruby

Which two of these three expressions are equal? Why?

```rb
{ "city" => "Miami", "state" => "Florida" }
{ :city => "Miami", :state => "Florida" }
{ city: "Miami", state: "Florida" }
```

Comment: "which" is trivial to check in an IRB session. And answer to the "why" is "because that's how it works"

Comment: Are you in the middle of taking a test, by any chance? :)

Comment: try them in irb :) look wich give you the same types on the keys in the hash. NOTE: use ruby >= 2.0.0

Comment: @Horacio, why >= v2.0?

Comment: @CarySwoveland after ruby 1.9 they introduce a "new" (now old) hash syntax http://effectif.com/ruby/update-your-project-for-ruby-19-hash-syntax

Comment: What does the documentation say? What did your experiments tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great discussion on using a Ruby `:symbol` vs a `String` [in another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby).

And here's a [nice discussion about the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198811/whats-the-difference-between-colon-and-fat-arrow) between the fat arrow `=>` syntax vs colons `:` in Ruby.

You can quickly check that the two hashes using `:symbols` are equivalent to each other, which are both different from the hash using strings:

```rb
a = {"city" => "Miami", "state" => "Florida"}
b = {:city => "Miami", :state => "Florida"}
c = {city: "Miami", state: "Florida"}

a == b
=> false

a == c
=> false

b == c
=> true
```

Comment: "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)" is useful.